# In flutter, how do I dynamically update an alert dialog's action list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to dynamically update an alert dialog's action list when something takes place in the alert dialog. Essentially, by default the dialog has a "Cancel" action button. But once the user does something in the dialog, I want it to have a "Cancel" and an "Accept" button. I have tried using a `StatefulBuilder`, which is how I am getting the rest of the dialog to update state. However, it is not working with the action buttons.

I've tried conditionally rendering the button, as well as generating a list to use for the dialog actions, and using `setState` to add to the list when an action takes place. Neither works, although other state updates within the dialog's content work with the `StatefulBuilder`. The dialog opens with only the "Cancel" action, and will not update to include the "Accept" action as well.

```
await showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    int? selectedRadio = 0;
    return AlertDialog(
      content: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(4, (int index) {
              return Radio<int>(
                value: index,
                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                onChanged: (int? value) {
                  setState(() => selectedRadio = value);
                },
              );
            }),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              selectedRadio == 1 ? TextButton(
                child: Text('Accept'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ) : SizedBox.Shrink(),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the AlertDialog inside the StatefulBuilder

```
return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
```

Comment: This works and is the simplest solution!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `StatefulWidget` to display your `AlertDialog`, and manage `selectedRadio` there. Also take advantage of Dart's `collection if` to handle the conditional button:

```
class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyDialog> createState() => _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  int selectedRadio = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          if (selectedRadio == 1)
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Accept'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
        ],
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(4, (int index) {
            return Radio<int>(
              value: index,
              groupValue: selectedRadio,
              onChanged: (int? value) {
                setState(() => selectedRadio = value!);
              },
            );
          }),
        ));
  }
}
```

After this, you can display your dialog for example like this:

```
TextButton(
    child: Text('Pressme'),
    onPressed: () async => await showDialog<void>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const MyDialog();
          },
        ))
```